# Laravel плюрализация

Tags: php, laravel, locale

Пытаюсь сделать локализацию/плюрализацию со множеством вариантов. Файл перевода:

```
'teachers' => '{0} Ни одного преподавателя
        |{1} :count преподаватель
        |[2-4] :count преподавателя
        |[5-20] :count преподавателей
        |[21-24] :count преподавателя
        |[25-Inf] :count преподавателей'
```

Но происходит странное. Пример вызова:

```
{{ Lang::choice('course.teachers', 0) }}
{{ Lang::choice('course.teachers', 1) }}
{{ Lang::choice('course.teachers', 2) }}
{{ Lang::choice('course.teachers', 5) }}
{{ Lang::choice('course.teachers', 16) }}
{{ Lang::choice('course.teachers', 22) }}
{{ Lang::choice('course.teachers', 46) }}
{{ Lang::choice('course.teachers', 12) }}
```

В результате имеем следующий вывод:

```
 - Ни одного преподавателя / все верно / 
 - 1 преподаватель         / все верно / 
 - 2 преподавателя         / все верно /
 - 5 преподавателей        / все верно /
 - 16 преподавателя        / ????????? /
 - 22 преподаватель        / ????????? /
 - 46 преподавателя        / ????????? /
 - 12 преподавателя        / ????????? /
```

Что я делаю не так? Или может еще какой есть способ решить проблему.

Comment: :count  для чего? в официале нет такой подстановки https://laravel.com/docs/master/localization#pluralization

Comment: И там не через тире а через запятую промежутки

Comment: @OlegShleif без `:count` не показывает число, а мне нужно его вывести. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Отправил pull request: https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/3548 :)

Comment: Да всегда пожалуйста)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
'teachers' => '{0} Ни одного преподавателя
    |{1} :count преподаватель
    |[2,4] :count преподавателя
    |[5,20] :count преподавателей
    |[21,24] :count преподавателя
    |[25,*] :count преподавателей'
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет никакого смысла в этой конструкции. Достаточно указать три формы слова -

```
'teachers' => 'Преподавателей|Преподователь|Преподователя'
```

Порядок форм мог перепутать в силу своей врожденной безграмотности. То, что написано выше корректно работать не будет.

PS: Вызывается так

```
trans_choice('messages.teachers', 10);
```

Comment: Ну это же gettext так работает, если указать кол во словоформ и правила их формирования, но вот в laravel так не вышло у меня

Comment: На 5.7 по крайней мере работает (проверенно). Возможно на более ранних версиях не было для русского правила. Можете глянуть в \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Translation\MessageSelector.php на своей версии.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю